# Update Shopify Variant returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, shopify

I am trying to update the inventory of an existing variant in shopify using the following json and c# code:

```
    var p = new
    {
            id = "220994352",
            inventory_quantity = "0"
    };

    string url = "https://somestore.myshopify.com/admin/variants/220994352.json";

    ShopifyAuthorizationState authState = (ShopifyAuthorizationState)HttpContext.Current.Session["shopify_auth_state"];
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "PUT";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", authState.AccessToken);

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(p);
    json = "{ variant: " + json + "}";

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    string result = "";
    try
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        WebHeaderCollection webHeaderCollection = ex.Response.Headers;
        foreach (var header in ex.Response.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(webHeaderCollection[header]);
        }
    }
```

However everytime I run this I get a 400 Bad request with no details about the error. 
I am get read the inventory without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you’ve set your scoped permissions when authorizing the app in order to have write access to products?

Can you post a link to a raw http response to show what exactly is being returned, including headers to see if there’s any more detail there?

Comment: The scope was already set, however I double checked the headers and my json was actually not valid. I was missing the double quotes around variant :(

Answer (score 1):

400 bad request usually means that data being sent is invalid.  And looking at your json would probably help you.  Try putting quotes around variant in your json string.

Comment: Thanks Colin. That was the issue. The same happens btw in the shopify the .net wrapper you created.

Comment: Actually, I only added the oAuth support to that .net wrapper.  I have a new .net wrapper coming out shortly that will work for all versions of .NET will be easier to use (hopefully).

Comment: Great. I am looking forward to it. Thanks